# field or property \"ListItemAllFields\" does not exist exception

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-clientobject

Below code credit goes to Vadim Gremyachev. My goal is to grant user access permissions to certain `SharePoint` folders by using the `CSOM`. The goal I am trying to achieve is to access the library called `JZhu`, and inside `JZhu` library, I have two folders `folder1` and `folder2`. I am trying to grant `Reader` permission to `folder1`. So far the code is not working because I get exception at line 6 saying:

> field or property \"ListItemAllFields\" does not exist

```
 ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://myRealUrl");
 Principal user = context.Web.EnsureUser(@"myLoginAccout");
 var folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("JZhu/folder1");
 var roleDefinition = context.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader);  //get Reader role
 var roleBindings = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context) { roleDefinition };
 folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);  //line 6
 folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(user, roleBindings);
 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably the error:

> field or property \"ListItemAllFields\" does not exist

occurs since you are using CSOM SDK that is *not compatible* with SharePoint server version, in particular your are using version 15 or 16 of SDK against SharePoint 2010.

The point is that for each SharePoint version have been released a separate SDKs:

- [SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786) 
  targets SharePoint 2010 Foundation/Server  (version 14)
- [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) targets SharePoint
  2013 (version 15)
- [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) targets SharePoint
  Online (version 16)

### How to get List Item associated with Folder via CSOM in SharePoint 2010

So, if my assumption is correct then you first need to install [SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786).

Secondly, since [Folder class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder(v=office.14).aspx) does **not** expose `ListItemAllFields` property in SharePoint 2010 CSOM API, you could utilize the following method for getting associated `ListItem` with `Folder`:

```
static class ListExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load List Item by Url 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list"></param>
    /// <param name="url"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ListItem LoadItemByUrl(this List list, string url)
    {
        var context = list.Context;
        var query = new CamlQuery
        {
            ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileRef'/><Value Type='Url'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", url),
        };
        var items = list.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        return items.Count > 0 ? items[0] : null;
    }
}
```

Then you could set unique permissions for a `Folder` as demonstrated below:

```
Principal user = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(accountName);
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var folderItem = list.LoadItemByUrl(folderUrl);
var roleDefinition = ctx.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader);  //get Reader role
var roleBindings = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) { roleDefinition };
folderItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);  //line 6
folderItem.RoleAssignments.Add(user, roleBindings);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

### How to get List Item associated with Folder via CSOM in SharePoint 2013

Since [Folder.ListItemAllFields property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.listitemallfields.aspx) is available in SharePoint **2013** CSOM, the following example demonstrates how to get `List Item` associated with `Folder`:

```
var folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
var folderItem = folder.ListItemAllFields;
```

Comment: i m off work this week so I have no way testing it. I will test it on Monday and accept the answer after I tested it.

Comment: Old post but I faced the issue today : LoadItemByUrl is a great approach, but as an improvement replacing <View> by <View Scope='RecursiveAll'> allows to get subfolders as well